# Why unable to use Application Insights with Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm recreating an Azure Function in a different Resource Group.

**Specifics:**

- OS: Linux
- Runtime: Python
- Region: South Central US
- Plan: App Service Plan (Premium V2 P2v2)

  - **Note:** This App Service Plan is used by another Function App as well

**Issue:**

- When I get to the "Monitor" step of setting up the new Function App, I'm disallowed to create an App Insights instance.

Error:

```
Application Insights code-less monitoring isn't supported with your selections of subscription, runtime stack, operating system, publish type, region, or resource group. If you want to keep these selections, you can use the Application Insights SDK to monitor your app.
```

[image]

**Why is this?** I'm literally duplicating a resource I already created in a different RG and it DOES have App Insights enabled.

Comment: Could you please create a new resource group and try again ? Because the issue may be caused by the region of resource group or something which already created in the resource group.

Comment: @HuryShen, I was able to get it to work by first creating the new Function App. After the Function app was created, I added App Insights just fine. Strange that Azure wouldn't configure App Insights during Function App creation.

Comment: Same settings seems no problems on my side.

Comment: Transient issue.

Comment: So the issue is solved now ?

Comment: The issue resolved itself, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, this is a transient issue. Sometimes azure portal will occur some strange issue, you can create a new resource or try again the next day.

For your question, even if the application insight can't be created when you create the function app because of some issues, you can also link to the application insight after you create the function app.

[image]

[image]